# DB2 stored procedure is not returning the result set

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I have a DB2 stored procedure which inserts a row in the database.  The stored procedure is as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA ( 
        IN P_USERID             CHAR(10),
        IN P_BUSINESSAREA       CHAR(10),
        IN P_SELECTEDIND        CHAR(1),
        IN P_DEFAULTIND         CHAR(1),
        IN P_LEGACYSYSTEM       CHAR(10),
        IN P_LEGACYLOGIN        CHAR(16),
        IN P_LEGACYPASSWORD     CHAR(16),
        IN P_OTHERLOGIN         CHAR(10),
        IN P_OTHERPASSWORD      CHAR(10),
        IN P_ADDSECURLOGIN      CHAR(10),
        IN P_ADDSECURPASSWORD   CHAR(10),
        IN P_LASTUPDATEUSERID   CHAR(10),
        IN P_LASTUPDATE         TIMESTAMP)

    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD ,
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *CS , 
    CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD ,
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER ,
    RDBCNNMTH = *RUW ,
    SRTSEQ = *HEX 

    P1 : BEGIN

    DECLARE TOTALCNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ; 

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
      SELECT Count (*) FROM USERBUSINESSAREA
       WHERE USERID            = P_USERID
         AND BUSINESSAREA = P_BUSINESSAREA;

    OPEN C1;
     FETCH C1 INTO TOTALCNT;
    CLOSE C1;

    IF ( TOTALCNT = 0) THEN 
      INSERT 
      INTO  USERBUSINESSAREA    
        (
            USERID,
            BUSINESSAREA,
            SELECTEDIND,
            DEFAULTIND,
            LEGACYSYSTEM,
            LEGACYLOGIN,
            LEGACYPASSWORD,
            OTHERLOGIN,
            OTHERPASSWORD,
            ADDSECURLOGIN,
            ADDSECURPASSWORD,
            LASTUPDATEUSERID,
            LASTUPDATE
        )
            VALUES  (P_USERID,
                     P_BUSINESSAREA,
                     P_SELECTEDIND,
                     P_DEFAULTIND,
                     P_LEGACYSYSTEM,
                     P_LEGACYLOGIN,
                     P_LEGACYPASSWORD,
                     P_OTHERLOGIN,
                     P_OTHERPASSWORD,
                     P_ADDSECURLOGIN,
                     P_ADDSECURPASSWORD,
                     P_LASTUPDATEUSERID,
                     P_LASTUPDATE);
      END IF;
    END P1;
```

When I try to execute the above stored procedure from Java/Spring-Integration layer, no result set is returned. What changes do I need to make for the above stored procedure to return a result set?

Comment: A result set is an open cursor. You don't have any open cursors when the procedure returns. And you don't need a result set if all you need to return is a single value -- use an `OUT` parameter instead.

Comment: Do you just want to know if you inserted the row in the DB?  As opposed to there already being one, I mean.  What actual information do you need in the Java layer?  What is the larger-picture task you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modified stored procedure worked for me( Just changed `WITH RETURN FOR` to `RETURN TO CALLER FOR`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA ( 
        IN P_USERID             CHAR(10),
        IN P_BUSINESSAREA       CHAR(10),
        IN P_SELECTEDIND        CHAR(1),
        IN P_DEFAULTIND         CHAR(1),
        IN P_LEGACYSYSTEM       CHAR(10),
        IN P_LEGACYLOGIN        CHAR(16),
        IN P_LEGACYPASSWORD     CHAR(16),
        IN P_OTHERLOGIN         CHAR(10),
        IN P_OTHERPASSWORD      CHAR(10),
        IN P_ADDSECURLOGIN      CHAR(10),
        IN P_ADDSECURPASSWORD   CHAR(10),
        IN P_LASTUPDATEUSERID   CHAR(10),
        IN P_LASTUPDATE         TIMESTAMP)

    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD ,
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *CS , 
    CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD ,
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER ,
    RDBCNNMTH = *RUW ,
    SRTSEQ = *HEX 

    P1 : BEGIN

    DECLARE TOTALCNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ; 

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
      SELECT Count (*)  FROM USERBUSINESSAREA
       WHERE USERID            = P_USERID
         AND BUSINESSAREA = P_BUSINESSAREA;

    OPEN C1;

     FETCH C1 INTO TOTALCNT;


    IF ( TOTALCNT = 0) THEN 
      INSERT 
      INTO  USERBUSINESSAREA    
        (
            USERID,
            BUSINESSAREA,
            SELECTEDIND,
            DEFAULTIND,
            LEGACYSYSTEM,
            LEGACYLOGIN,
            LEGACYPASSWORD,
            OTHERLOGIN,
            OTHERPASSWORD,
            ADDSECURLOGIN,
            ADDSECURPASSWORD,
            LASTUPDATEUSERID,
            LASTUPDATE
        )
            VALUES  (P_USERID,
                     P_BUSINESSAREA,
                     P_SELECTEDIND,
                     P_DEFAULTIND,
                     P_LEGACYSYSTEM,
                     P_LEGACYLOGIN,
                     P_LEGACYPASSWORD,
                     P_OTHERLOGIN,
                     P_OTHERPASSWORD,
                     P_ADDSECURLOGIN,
                     P_ADDSECURPASSWORD,
                     P_LASTUPDATEUSERID,
                     P_LASTUPDATE);
      END IF;

    END P1;
```

Comment: Since your cursor is only expected to have one row, and you do a `FETCH` in the procedure, the result set returned to the caller will be positioned at the end, in other words, the caller will not fetch anything from it any more.

Comment: @mustaccio yes..you are correct. It won't contain anything.The only difference is that the result set object will not be null. I require the result not to be null at the Java end. So it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to return?

- There is a cursor where you select the quantity of elements, and assign it to a variable. After that, the cursor is closed.
- Depending on the retrieved quantity, you perform an insert.

I do not know what you expect:

- Do you want to return a result set? Then you should have an opened cursor. (e.g. select * from USERBUSINESSAREA)
- Do you want to return the retrieved value in the cursor? Then, as @mustaccio said, you can add a OUT parameter, and then just assign the value.

Comment: ...and this is a comment, not really an answer.